# Can I add a custom static claim to auth tokens with a AAD OIDC app registration?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-identity-platform

I have a basic Azure AD App Registration. This is a non-interactive client IE console/machine client with a secret and no redirect URI. I would also like this to also work for interactive clients however.

How can I add a claim to my token called `"hello": "world"`?

Answer (score 1):

To add a custom claim like  **`"hello": "world"`** in the token, you can create claim mapping policy using **PowerShell**.

1)Make sure to have **`AzureADPreview`** module installed, before running below commands.

```
Connect-AzureAD
New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('
{
    "ClaimsMappingPolicy":
    {
        "Version":1,"IncludeBasicClaimSet":"true", 
        "ClaimsSchema": [{"Source":"user","ID":"extensionattribute1","SamlClaimType":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/hello","JwtClaimType":"hello"}]
    }
}') -DisplayName "HelloExtraClaim" -Type "ClaimsMappingPolicy"
```

**Output:**

[image]

2)Note the **`ID`** of the policy and assign it to your service principal using below command:

```
Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id serviceprincipal_ObjectID -RefObjectId policy_ID
```

3)To confirm whether the policy is assigned or not, run below command:

```
Get-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id serviceprincipal_ObjectID
```

**Output:**

[image]

4)To assign **value** to that claim, sign in as admin to **[Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)** and run the below query:

```json
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me
{
"onPremisesExtensionAttributes": 
    {
        "extensionAttribute1": "world"
    }
}
```

**Response:**
[image]

5)Make sure to set **`"acceptMappedClaims": true`** in App's Manifest like below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App registrations -> Your App -> Manifest***

[image]

6)Go to ***Expose an API*** tab and set **`Application ID URI`** to your domain like below:

[image]

7)Generate a token to your application by signing with admin account.

***After decoding the above *ID token* in [**jwt.ms**](https://jwt.ms/), I got the claim **`"hello": "world"`** successfully as below:***

[image]

**Credits**: [How to add custom user defined claims to azure ad token | GitHub](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-desktop-msgraph-v2/issues/50#issuecomment-598429976) by TiagoBrenck

Comment: This is helpful, but this does not work for access tokens.