Add organisation chart to Azure Active Directory token claims
I need to include organisational chart information to the token claims when they are issued by Azure Active Directory.
Assuming that my company has this organisation:

For example, when i login as 'Roary Moody', i would like to receive in the token that 'Francis Jeffferson' is my CFO.
Are there any way to do this?

AFAIK, there is no direct way to include organization chart in token claims. You need to create custom claim and update it's value for every user. Refer if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73389590/can-i-add-a-custom-static-claim-to-auth-tokens-with-a-aad-oidc-app-registration/73399831#73399831

Usually, you can run below Microsoft Graph API call to get the details of user hierarchical to signed-in user in organization chart by expanding manager attribute:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$expand=manager($select=id,displayName,jobTitle)

Response:

Alternatively, you can create claim mapping policy by running below sample PowerShell script to get the same value in custom claim of token:
#Install-Module Microsoft.Graph
Connect-MgGraph
$policyDefinition = @{
    definition = '{
        "ClaimsMappingPolicy": {
            "Version": 1,
            "IncludeBasicClaimSet": true,
            "ClaimsSchema": [
                {"Source": "user", "ID": "extensionattribute1", "SamlClaimType": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/manager", "JwtClaimType": "manager"}
            ]
        }
    }'
    displayName = "AddManager"
}

$Policy = New-MgPolicyClaimMappingPolicy -BodyParameter $policyDefinition
Get-MgPolicyClaimMappingPolicy -ClaimsMappingPolicyId $Policy.Id | fl

Response:

Now, assign this policy to the service principal from which you are generating the token with these commands:
$servicePrincipalId = "spObjectId" 
$policyId = "policyId" 

$params = @{
    "@odata.id" = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/policies/claimsMappingPolicies/$policyId"
}

New-MgServicePrincipalClaimMappingPolicyByRef -ServicePrincipalId $servicePrincipalId -BodyParameter $params
Get-MgServicePrincipalClaimMappingPolicy -ServicePrincipalId $servicePrincipalId | fl

Response:

Now, update manager claim value in user's properties by running these commands:
$userId = "userId"

$params = @{
    onPremisesExtensionAttributes = @{
        extensionAttribute1 = "ManagerName(jobTitle)"
    }
}
Update-MgUser -UserId $userId -BodyParameter $params

Response:

Make sure to enable below settings in app registration's Manifest:

Now, I exposed an API by adding custom scope in app registration like this:

In my case, I used Implicit flow to generate access token for which below options should be enabled:

When I ran below authorization URL in browser by signing in with updated user, I got token with manager claim successfully like this:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=appID&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms&scope=api://appID/custom.read&state=12345&nonce=12345


Reference:
Fetching Organization Chart - API - Microsoft Q&A by CarlZhao-MSFT
